# ImportError while importing models in a different file in same directory

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and I am enjoying it a lot. But, yesterday I tried splitting views into different files, but importing the model in that new file shows `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I am using the same statement as in view

```
from .models import Email
```

And they are in the same directory. I even tried from models import Email but it says the same ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: How are you running your code? Relative imports are only meaningful if you execute a module as part of a package, e.g. `python3 -m my_package.module`. You can't use relative imports if you're running a Python file as a standalone script, e.g. `python3 module.py`.

Comment: Are you using Django's runserver command to run your project? Does your app have an `__init__.py` file? Did you try `from <yourappname>.models import Email`?

Comment: Can you show us your file layout?